# houses pset7 works fine with me but doesn't work when run through check50

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, cs50

the pset i'm working on has 2 parts, both of which work fine with me. however when i run these through check50 i would get 1/6. here is a link to what i should do in the pset: [pset](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/7/houses/#:%7E:text=submit50%20cs50/problems/2020/x/houses) and these are the errors i get: [errors](https://submit.cs50.io/check50/89237a739eee1e7a9e2d70e68cfc9e64b3cd0526).

here is my code for import.py:

```
from cs50 import SQL
from sys import argv, exit
import csv

db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

if len(argv) != 2:
    print("error")
    exit(1)
    
if argv[1] != "characters.csv":
    print("error")
    exit(1)
    
with open(argv[1], "r") as CSVfile:
    CSVfile = csv.DictReader(CSVfile, delimiter = ',')
    chars = list(CSVfile)
    
    for row in chars:
        name = row["name"]
        birth = row["birth"]
        house = row["house"]
        
        full = name.split( )
        
        if len(full) == 2:
            
            first = full[0]
            last = full[1]
            
            db.execute("INSERT INTO students(first, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", first, last, house, birth)
            
        elif len(full) == 3:
            
            first = full[0]
            middle = full[1]
            last = full[2]
            
            db.execute("INSERT INTO students(first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", first, middle, last, house, birth)
```

here is my code for roster:

```
from cs50 import SQL
from sys import argv, exit
import csv

if len(argv) != 2:
    print("error")
    exit(1)
    
db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

results = db.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE house = ? ORDER BY last ASC, first ASC", argv[1])


for row in results:
    
    if 'middle' != None:
        print(f"{row['first']} {row['middle']} {row['last']}, born {row['birth']}")
    
    else:
        print(f"{row['first']} {row['last']}, born {row['birth']}")
```

i've already talked to a mentor about it and i've fixed the mistakes that he has mentioned so they're irrelevant. thanks in advance.

edit:

i removed this part:

```
if argv[1] != "characters.csv":
        print("error")
        exit(1)
```

as it is a mistake to hardcode the name of the csv file into my code. this has improved things a lot. however, i now have faced a problem in roster. what i meant to see as output was the student's full name and birth year. some students don't have a middle name so i tried to make an if condition to see if 'middle' exists in this name or not:

```
if 'middle' != None:
            print(f"{row['first']} {row['middle']} {row['last']}, born {row['birth']}")
        
        else:
            print(f"{row['first']} {row['last']}, born {row['birth']}")
```

however, what i would instead get as input for students with no middle name would be something like this: Lavender None Brown, born 1979

Answer (score 1):

From the spec:

> - Your program should accept the name of a CSV file as a command-line    argument.
> - If the incorrect number of command-line arguments are provided, your    program should print an error and exit.
> - You may assume that the CSV file will exist, and will have columns    name, house, and birth.

The name of the CSV file should *not* be hardcoded, as it is here `if argv[1] != "characters.csv":`

But wait there's more! (after question edit)

This `if 'middle' != None:` is *always true*! Why? Because `'middle'` is a string literal. Maybe you meant `row['middle']`?

Comment: thank you! this made everything in import.py correct. however i am now getting an unusual output in roster. i edited my question so you could see it

Comment: info added to answer